# Unhanded Exception thrown following Nativescript 2.2.0 update

Tags: android, nativescript

I just updated to Nativescript 2.2.0, everything built fine and runs fine through most of my app. When loading a specific view though I get the below unhandled exception along with the stack trace. This was not occuring before updating the core platform and modules. When I search for the 'disableNotifications' property mentioned in the stack trace I find nothing of the sort in my project. After doing some digging seems to be apart of the core framework some where, any body have any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the actual chunk of code where the error is occuring in the core observable module. Have they removed the ability to add properties in the following way `var model = new Observable({propName: 'value'});`?

```
Observable.js code where exception is thrown:
    Observable.prototype._setCore = function (data) {
        this.disableNotifications[data.propertyName] = true;
        var newValue = WrappedValue.unwrap(data.value);
        this[data.propertyName] = newValue;
        delete this.disableNotifications[data.propertyName];
    };
```

**Here is how I tend to instantiate my Observables within my view models:**

```
var model = new Observable({
    measurements: new ObservableArray([]),
    recentMeasurement: {},
    notificationsEnabled: appSettings.getBoolean('notificationsEnabled', true),
    patientFirstName: "",
    patientLastName: "",
    units: "",
    hasMultipleConnections: true
});
```

**Another Example**

```
var model = new Observable({        
    countries:  new ValueList([
        { ValueMember: "FR", DisplayMember: L('france') },
        { ValueMember: "DE", DisplayMember: L('germany') },
        { ValueMember: "IT", DisplayMember: L('italy') },
        { ValueMember: "NL", DisplayMember: L('netherlands') },
        { ValueMember: "ES", DisplayMember: L('spain') },
        { ValueMember: "SE", DisplayMember: L('sweden') },
        { ValueMember: "GB", DisplayMember: L('unitedkingdom') }]),  
    selectedCountry: 0,
    countryPlaceholder: L('select_country')
});
```

**Original Stack Trace**

> ```
> com.tns.NativeScriptException:  Calling js method onTouch failed
>
> TypeError: Cannot set property 'disableNotifications' of undefined
> File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.CareGiver/files/app/tns_modules/ui/gestures/gestures.js", line: 97, column: 40
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'Observable._setCore',
> file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.CareGiver/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js',
> line: 136, column: 54     Frame: function:'Observable.set',
> file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.CareGiver/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js',
> line: 129, column: 14     Frame: function:'Observable',
> file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.CareGiver/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js',
> line: 50, column: 26  Frame: function:'Observable',
> file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.CareGiver/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js',
> line: 47, column: 38  Frame: function:'MeasurementViewModel',
> file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.CareGiver/files/app/models/measurement-view-model.js',
> line: 16, column:
> file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.CareGiver/files/app/models/measurement-view-model.js',
> line: 16, column:
> ```

Comment: When you type "tns info"; does everything say running "2.2.0" or do you perhaps have one of the files out of sync.  (i.e. Runtimes, core modules and TNS should all be 2.2.x)

Comment: nativescript, tns-core-modules, tns-android and tns-ios all show as being up to date at 2.2.0

Comment: Have you tried to deinstall the application from the device; and then to do another run.  Maybe something left over from 2.1?   The other things is what is on line 16 of your measurement-view-model.js

Comment: Line 16 is the start of my Observable instantiation. Seems like the way I'm instantiating my obeservables is problematic in several areas after this update. I've updated the question with an example of how I instantiate them.

Comment: I noticed someone else on Github reporting something similar https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2457#issuecomment-236075561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in my case the problem seemed to be due to having nested Observables. By removing the nested observable the exception was no longer being thrown:

**Old Way**

```
var model = new Observable({
    measurements: new ObservableArray([]),
    recentMeasurement: {},
    notificationsEnabled: appSettings.getBoolean('notificationsEnabled', true),
    patientFirstName: "",
    patientLastName: "",
    units: "",
    hasMultipleConnections: true
});
```

**New Way**

```
var model = new Observable({
    measurements: [],
    recentMeasurement: {},
    notificationsEnabled: appSettings.getBoolean('notificationsEnabled', true),
    patientFirstName: "",
    patientLastName: "",
    units: "",
    hasMultipleConnections: true
});
```

This change also seems to be causing some problems with a few of the plugins I have installed and am using. You can see this mentioned [here on Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2457#issuecomment-236075561/)