# ObservableArray causing app to stall

Tags: nativescript

I'm attempting to use an `ObservableArray` similar to the grocery list tutorial, but whenever I add the ObservableArray to my code-behind file's Observable, my app will not load the respective xml page. My app stalls at the previous page. Here's the respective code:

home.js:

```
var Group_List_View_Model = require("../../shared/view-models/list_groups_view_model");
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

var group_list = new Group_List_View_Model([]);


var page_data = new Observable({
    group_list: group_list,
    load_groups: false
});


exports.onNavigatingTo = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = page_data;
}
```

list_groups_view_model.js:

```
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

function Group_List_View_Model(items) {
    var view_model = new ObservableArray(items);
    return view_model;    
}

module.exports = Group_List_View_Model;
```

When I comment out only `return view_model;`, my app no longer stalls. The same applies when I comment out only `group_list: group_list,`. My app does not like something about the ObservableArray. Any insight on what my be causing the problem?

Update: My app also doesn't like it when I put the ObservableArray directly in my code-behind file:

home.js

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

var group_list = new ObservableArray([]);

var page_data = new Observable({
    group_list: group_list,
    load_groups: false
});
```

Update2: I'm using firebase in my app, and my console is giving this error:

```
JS: Error in firebase.init: Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
```

Although, there is no firebase code related to this observable array at this point, and the array is also empty.

Update3: Related issue [Unhanded Exception thrown following Nativescript 2.2.0 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884661/unhanded-exception-thrown-following-nativescript-2-2-0-update)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is currently being assessed: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2457#issuecomment-236075561/